# How to Fix the exception received from poco library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, exception, poco-libraries

When client create an instant on *SenderThread*. It can send data to and from.
But when client goes for suspend mode and come back from suspend. The last created threads get exception on
resume. and no data is sent.

**Exception Details received :**

> displayText = Exception
>
> message =
>
> name    = Exception
>
> className = N4Poco9ExceptionE

Here is the code:

```
class SenderThread: public Poco::Runnable
{
public:
    MyThread(const std::string& msg):
        Msg(msg);
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        try {
        SendData(msg);
       } catch(Exception exp) {
           std::cout<<"displayText = "<<e.displayText()<<std::endl;
           std::cout<<"message = "<<e.message()<<std::endl;
           std::cout<<"name = "<<e.name()<<std::endl;
           std::cout<<"className = "<<e.className()<<std::endl;
  
        }

    }

private:
    std::string Msg;
    
};
```

How can I get more details on the exception and how to handle this exception?.

Edited After **Günter Obiltschnig** comment:

I am able to catch the proper exception.

```
 displayText = Invalid argument 
 name = Invalid argument
```

Some time i see socket closed exception. When  system goes to suspend mode then all the socket is closed by system(os). Now upon resume application tries to open the socket again it throw error in the Poco::Net::Socket::Socket(Poco::Net::Socket const&). any help on this please

Answer (score 4):

You have to catch the exception by (const) reference in order to get useful information out of it.

```
catch (const Poco::Exception& exc)
{
    std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I am able to catch the proper exception. displayText = Invalid argument
name = Invalid argument and some time i see socket closed exception. When after system goes to suspend mode then all the socket is closed by system. Now upon resume application tries to open the socket again it throw error in the  Poco::Net::Socket::Socket(Poco::Net::Socket const&). any help on this please

Comment: My code crash when  fresh re-connection after suspend  is done 
@Günter Obiltschnig  Process 909343  terminated SIGSEGV code=1 fltno=11 libpos.so@_ZN4Poco3Net6SocketC1ERKS1_+0x0000000000000018) mapaddr=000000000023d8